# How to run php code in html file on windows server?

Tags: .htaccess

I have used .htaccess file with below code
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

it works fine in local but when I upload my files on server it is not working fine.
My all pages have html extension.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a mapping to the PHP exe for the `html` extension.

IIS has a list of extensions and, based on the file extension will choose the server side processor based on this list.

If you right-click on "Web Sites" in IIS and select "Properties", you can change your ISAPI extensions.

Find the htm and html extensions and change the executable to be the same as they are for .php