# Can I run a PHP code within an HTML file in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, windows-server-2019

I have been trying to understand a way to run PHP within .html in my server 2019. If there is a way to do so? can someone give me some guidance on it?

There was a post on this already [How to run php code in html file on windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021203/how-to-run-php-code-in-html-file-on-windows-server), but it does not seem to be much help.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "run PHP within .html"? If you want to host PHP-Files on your Windows Server you could install or set up IIS or any other webserver.

Comment: I have been reading that if you add .htaccess file to your server (possibly? this is what I am trying to figure out), you can run something php code in a file with extension .html. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute PHP code in html, you can do that only in .php file with the help of a web server.

You can have an ajax call that will interact with a url (which can be a PHP file resource) and that can return some processed result.

`.php` file can have html and it will work all fine but you need a web server to run the `.php` files. You can install wamp/xampp on your windows server and use that to do some processing using your .php file.

Comment: I have been researching and reading around that by utilizing a .htaccess file there is the possibility to do so, Am I totally off? There are a lot of references out there, this is just an example: https://deano.me/2015/12/php-inside-html-files-using-htaccess/

Comment: what's your business requirement? share it, maybe we can give you some solution.

Comment: No business requirement, just personal development.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why you would do this, .htm and .php files are both common on the internet. You either have to provide a full link containing the file type or perform some sort of rewrite to remove the extension for end user simplicity and this process would be fairly similar whether its .htm or .php youre dealing with.

To answer the question though, i havn't personally done this, but the link you provided implies it should be possible. What they're talking about is adjusting the "Handler Mappings" in IIS. This can be done at two levels, either at Webserver level or Website level. If you open Internet Information Services Manager (assumes you root access to the windows server and not just access to upload a website, if you don't the server admin will need to do this!) you will get a tree down the left side called "Connections". Under Connections either:

Click the PC Name (a server with a globe icon) for server level
Or
Click the website (just a globe under the sites folder for site Website level)

Then you need to find the Handler Mappings on the main window under **IIS > Handler Mappings**.

they are then suggesting creating a mapping for .htm and .html that follows the same rules as the .php mappings. I would read up on this page and what it does though.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/

A couple of things to note:

- You may have to install PHP yourself using the Web Platform Installer as i recall it's not there by default on all (if any) versions of IIS. Until you do this you may not see the PHP handler mappings mentioned in the above section.
- you will likely need a mapping for .htm and .html separately.
- .htaccess files dont work in IIS, you usually have to find a web.config equivalent, i suspect you wont find one for this though due to how IIS works.
- If you dont own the server or all of the sites on it, you may wantr to do this at website level first to make sure it doesn't break any of the other sites.

Comment: Very resourceful, thank you. I am pretty new to the Windows Server world. I will test a few things according to what you shared and we'll go from there.